# Enable autofill/autocomplete for html pages alongwith angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, html

I am having problem with autofill/autocomplete/auto suggestions as we get in asp forms. How can i do it using angularjs with html controls when I focus them. (not from database). What i want is shown in image.

[Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mirVd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Angular itself does not provide this functionality. You can use one of dozens external ui libraries for this.
For example Angular Material or Kendo UI

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index

But there are many others more

Comment: Problem solved by just adding "name" attribute in the control so that browser can understand how to and with which control to interact. ;)